# Lotus Notes client crashes when opening subforms

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have a couple of nested subforms in one of the applications I'm maintaining. The form crashes after I reload around the 6th subform. To clarify: I have 10 main subforms on a form and each can dynamically load 6 different subforms. The client just hangs itself after the form is saved.

I found an official statement here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LO58909
Does anyone has a better solution than "do not use them"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider redesigning the form/application.
If IBM says "don't do it, it will not be fixed", that sounds pretty set in stone for me. Remember, Notes applications are designed to be backwards compatible, if there is a limitation in an earlier version that causes a crash, it will probably not be allowed in a later version. Supposed the bug is in version 7, and they fix it in version 9. What do you think will happen when that Notes 9 application is opened by a user still on Notes 7, or even 8?

So don't do it. :-)

The workaround is to redesign the application in a better way.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the answer. However they say that this was due to an programming error. Same application works in 9 beta fine. So they did something. But anyhow, I guess I have to redesign it ...

Comment: Okay. It seems like I could fix it. Apparently Notes was not able to handle the doc being closed and reloaded several times. I did it with some help of google on how to refresh subforms - since IBM has such a great help.

Comment: Where IBM says it is a programming error, I think they refer to the IBM programer that wrote the code, i.e. it is a bug.